# Clever Solutions: Find $\min_{a,b} E[(V -(aU+b))^2]$ without differentiation?

Tags: probability, parameter-estimation

Let $(U,V)$ be joint random variables (assume zero means for simplicity). It is well known that
\begin{align}
\min_{a,b} E[(V -(aU+b))^2],
\end{align}
is minimized by  $a= \frac{E[VU]}{E[U^2]}$ and $b=0$. This answer results in what is know as the best linear estimator.

The classical proof of this expands the expression and finds partial derivatives with respect to $a$ and $b$.

**My question:**    Are there alternative proofs that do not use differentiation?  For example, can this be found via some known inequalities like Jensen or Cauchy-Schwarz?  In other words, I am looking for **interesting and unique solutions** to this old problem.

**Edit** I didn't ask this originality, but can it be also done with minimal expansion.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(V-(aU+b))^2 &= \mathbb{E}V^2 - 2 (a \mathbb{E} UV + b \mathbb{E} V) + \mathbb{E}(aU+b)^2 \\
&= (a^2 \mathbb{E}U^2 - 2a \mathbb{E} UV) + b^2 + \mathbb{E}V^2
\end{align*}
Note that these are separable quadratics in $a, b$ (since the cross term $ab$ vanishes because we assumed $\mathbb{E} U = 0$), and each is minimized at the vertex, given by $x = -\gamma_1/2\gamma_2$ in $\gamma_2 x^2 + \gamma_1 x + \gamma_0 = 0$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
a &= \frac{2 \mathbb{E} UV}{2 \mathbb{E}U^2} = \frac{\mathbb{E} UV}{\mathbb{E}U^2} \\
b &= -\frac{0}{2\cdot 1} = 0
\end{align*}

Comment: Why do you assume that $E(U)=0$?

Comment: @callculus "assume zero means for simplicity"

Comment: Ah ok. I´ve didn´t noticed it. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

If you consider $E(XY)$ as scalar product of random variables, then your have the following meaning:

- $E(X^2)$ — is the squared length
- $E((X-Y)^2)$ — is the squared distance between $X$ and $Y$

Using this interpretation your problem is to find the random variable $aU+b$ that is the closest one to the random variable $V$. But all random variables of the form $aU+b$ are linear combinations of the random variable $U$ and constant $1$. So you just need to find the projection of random variable $V$ on this plane.

The difference $V - (aU+b)$ should be orthogonal to $U$ and $1$. The corresponding scalar product should be zero. So you have two equations
$$
\begin{cases}
\langle V - (aU+b), 1 \rangle = E(V - (aU+b))=0 \\
\langle V - (aU+b), U \rangle = E((V - (aU+b))\cdot U)=0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

From this system your get $a$ and $b$ :)